cpu high usage problems on ubuntu 23.10
I have recently upgraded to ubuntu 23.10, and have noticed some weird performance problems.
When idling, my system seems fine, however as soon as I started using my mouse, the gnome-shell's cpu usage jumps to around 70% usage and stays there.
It gets even worse whenever I hover over icons or open a window, spiking the usage up too 100%.
Please help

Have you tried (installing and) opening htop to see which process is responsible for the CPU use?

I used the system monitor that comes with ubuntu, looks like it was the gnome-shell process

Not ideal, but after checking journalctl -f, I noticed it was full of:
g_closure_add_invalidate_notifier: assertion 'closure->n_inotifiers < CLOSURE_MAX_N_INOTIFIERS' failed

A quick Google search later and it seems turning off desktop zoom fixes the issue.
